# Apple Server to Server notification not receiving from the sandbox for testing subscription renewal

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I am trying to update the user's subscription renewal state. I had set up the endpoint in the app information section "URL for App Store Server Notifications" in the app information. But didn't receive any notification. Also, I had tried to set up revenuecat but got no notification. Does anyone know about this issue?

Comment: Maybe your Server doesn’t apply to Apple’s requirements or it isn’t configured correctly. Hard to tell without more informations

Comment: Hi, This is resolved, i created the new sandbox account and started receiving the notifications.